# service is returning object and ngFor not accepting object format data

Tags: angular, angular6

I am working on Angular Application where 
I'm trying to display some info in the dom but I get this error as ngFor  not  accepting object format data 
What Im trying to do is iterate over data.

> error is ->> Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and
>   iterables are allowed

as I ngFor only accepts

I am putting code for the same

.ts file

```
      matchUid: any;
  sportsType: any;
  token: any;
  matchData:any = [];
  team1: any;
  team2: any;

      matchstatus: any;
      tournamentName: any;
      jsonData: any;
      matchScore: any;
      matchDetails: any = [];
     ngOnInit() {

        this._route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {  this.matchUid  = params.get('matchId') ,  this.matchstatus = params.get('status')  , this.sportsType = parseInt(params.get('ttypeid'))
        console.log(this.matchstatus);
          })

          this.loadData();
      }


     // match Indivisual Data
      loadData() {
                this.token =  localStorage.getItem('putoken');
                let token = 'Bearer ' + this.token;
                let bodyData = { MatchID: this.matchUid, tTypeID: this.sportsType };
                let liveContestsBody = {
                  matchId: this.matchUid,
                  matchStatus: this.matchstatus,
                };

                this.rest.matchIndevidualData(bodyData, token).then(
                            result => {
                              this.matchData = result;

                              this.team1 = this.matchData.data.team1Name;
                              this.team2 = this.matchData.data.team2Name;
                              this.tournamentName = this.matchData.data.tournamentName;
                              console.log('1');
                              console.log(typeof(result));
                              console.log(this.matchData);
                               },
                            err => {
                              this.router.navigate(['ErrorPage']);
                              console.log('connection failed!...');
                            }
                );

                this.rest.getMatchScore(liveContestsBody).then(
                            result => {
                              this.jsonData = result;
                              console.log(2);
                              console.log(typeof(result));
                              console.log('data');
                              console.log(this.jsonData);
                              if (this.jsonData.status == '1') {
                                this.matchScore = this.jsonData.data;
                                console.log('match details');

                                console.log(this.matchScore);
                              } else {
                                console.log('No data found');
                              }
                            },
                            err => {
                              this.router.navigate(['ErrorPage']);
                              console.log('connection failed');
                            }
                );


                this.rest.getLiveContests(liveContestsBody,token).then(
                                  result => {
                                    this.jsonData = result;
                                    console.log('3');
                                    console.log(typeof(result));
                                    console.log(this.jsonData);
                                    if (this.jsonData.status == '1') {
                                      this.matchData = this.jsonData.data;
                                      console.log(this.matchData);
                                    } else {
                                      console.log('No data found');
                                      }
                                  },
                                  err => {
                                    this.router.navigate(['ErrorPage']);
                                    console.log('connection failed');
                                  }
                );



      }
```

.html

```
<div style='background: crimson;
padding: 21px;color: #fff'>
<h1>  {{matchstatus}} Match </h1>

<span> <strong> Match: </strong>  {{team1}} vs {{team2}}  </span>

<div>
  <p> <strong> Tournament name: </strong> {{tournamentName}}  </p>

<p> <strong> status: </strong> {{matchstatus}} </p>
</div>

</div>

<div>
  <p><bold> Score Card </bold> </p>
  <div *ngFor="let matchScoreData of matchScore">
      <p>{{ matchScoreData.teamName }}</p>
      <p>
        {{ matchScoreData.run }} - {{ matchScoreData.wicket }}<span>({{ matchScoreData.over }})</span>
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
<button style='    width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
background: tomato;
color: #fff;
' ion-button clear full class="team-preview" (click)="playerPoint()">Players Point</button>
</div>

<div class="contest-section">
    <div *ngIf="!matchData.length">

      <h2>You have not joined any contest in this match</h2>
     <button>  <a (click)="goToMatchCenter()">Please Try another match</a> </button>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let match of matchData; let i = index" (click)="goCashContest(match.contestId)">
      <div align-items-center>

            <h3>Winners</h3>
            <p>{{ match.totalWinners }}</p>


          <div>

            <h3>Winnings</h3>
            <p>{{ match.totalWinningAmount }}</p>
          </div>

        <div>
          <div>

            <h3>Entry Fee</h3>
            <p>&#8377;{{ match.entryFee }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>

            <h3>Rank</h3>
            <p>{{ match.rank }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>

            <h3>Join With</h3>
            <p>{{ match.joinWith }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>

            <h3>Points</h3>
            <p>{{ match.points }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button>Leader Bord</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Like the error says, you can not use *ngFor over an object. Change your service to return an array. Have a closer look at what `matchScore` exactly is. Is it an object?

Comment: the reason for the above error might be you are not getting an array object in "matchData" instead you might be getting the only object. And ngFor iterates only over array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seems matchIndevidualData() Method does not return Array Data. So You should push "result" into "matchDetails" array. 
So, change this:

```
this.matchData = result;
```

With this:

```
this.matchData.push(result);
```